# sql prepared statement retuning empty json array

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have 3 radio buttons when i select one of them i want the dropdown list to be loaded from the corresponding table so I declared the variable `$choice` to save the state of the radio button and assign 2 new variables `$table` to set the name of the table from which i will get the data and another `$secolumn` to set the column name from each table
then connect to the mysql DB with a prepared statement

```
<?php
include "connect.php";//to connect to the mysql DB
$table ='';
$secolumn ='';
if (isset($_GET["table_cond"])) {
    $choice = $_GET["table_cond"];
    if ($choice == "table_fixe") {
        $table = "cr002t_cours_fixe";
        $secolumn ="CR002_DEV_DIN";
    } elseif ($choice == "table_billets") {
        $table = "cr004t_cours_billet";
        $secolumn = "CR004_DEV_BILLC";
    } elseif ($choice == "table_itqb") {
        $table = "cr005t_cours_intbq_comp";
        $secolumn = "CR005_DEV_COMP";
    } else {
        echo "choose a button";
    }
}

$sql ="SELECT DISTINCT GR027DEVISE, GR027LIB 
        FROM gr027t_devises D, ".$table." T 
        WHERE D.GR027DEVISE = ?;";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
    echo"sql statement failed";
}else {
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $secolumn);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
}
$currency_array=[];
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id = $row['GR027DEVISE'];
    $name = $row['GR027LIB'];
    $currency_array[] =array("id"=>$id,"name"=>$name);
}
echo json_encode(['currency_array'=>$currency_array]);
?>
```

then in the front end i have added the following script when ckicked on one of the radio buttons
/the id of the drop down list id sel_curr_name

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkTABLE(table_cond){
    var sel_curr_name=document.querySelector('#sel_curr_name');
    var content='';
    
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
        url :'/myfolder/getcurrencylist.php?table_cond='+table_cond,
        success:function(data){
            json=JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(json.currency_array);
            $.each( json.currency_array, function( key, value ) {
                content+='<option value='+value.id+'>'+value.name+'</option>'
                });
                sel_curr_name.innerHTML=content;
        }
    })
}
```

the problem in the browser console when I select on of the buttons I get an empty array=> and in the network tab I get this {"currency_array":[]}

Comment: Did you run the query in phpMyAdmin to see if that return any rows based on that query?

Comment: You are using very old syntax for your joins. You also haven't defined a join relationship. You should use `join TABLE_NAME` and `on` with the defined relationship, or `using(`) if  the tables use the same column name. Does the query return results when executed directly?

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah it works fine and  get what i nned in the php myadmin

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: @user3783243 i have replaces the query with $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT gr027t_devises.GR027DEVISE, gr027t_devises.GR027LIB FROM gr027t_devises INNER JOIN ".$table." ON gr027t_devises.GR027DEVISE = ?"; where $table is the name of the table when the radio is selected and ? column name of the selected table

Comment: You need to use the `on` for the relationship you are joining. Then use a `where` clause for what do you want to select.